# Can I place xml files, jar files, log files inside the java package of src folder

Tags: java, package

I want to keep my xml files ,jar files and .log files inside the java package of src folder corresponding to specific category .Is it correct way to place like that.Can any one suggest better approach .suppose,I have test cases related to order placing,order processing and order dispatching.I made three packages for these three order management tasks and putting java test case scripts(java classes) in respective package. Now I want to place xml files needed by the scripts in the order placing package in the same package.Similarly for remaining packages also.

Comment: What do you mean by "corresponding to specific category"? What are .log files? (If they're diagnostic log files, they'd surely be generated by the code at execution time...) It doesn't sound like any of this is source code, so it shouldn't be in the src directory...

Comment: I have many test cases that are categorized into many categories and are placed in to different packages,that is where I want to place the config.xml files and generated test results files(.log) files

Comment: It's still really not clear what you mean - I suggest you put a lot more context into your question. Additionally, you have a `setup-project` tag in your question... it's not clear what you expect that to mean. I inferred it to mean you were creating an installer, but now I suspect that's not the case. More detail would be useful.

Comment: Again, you should be putting all of this information *in the question*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want to keep my xml files ,jar files and .log files inside the java package of src folder

Sure, if they are *inputs.* .log files sound like *outputs* to me. You need to understand that resources are not files, and that packages are not directories. Consider the case where the .jar or .war or .ear file is never unpacked.